# UDF in Pyspark causing no module named pyspark error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I hope ya'll can help

The below, I have a UDF that does nothing, just returns the same value that was input into it. But, it doesn't work.

When I run the script WITHOUT the UDF, it runs fine,

As soon as I add the UDF, I get '/usr/bin/python: No module named pyspark' - obviously it is found, because otherwise the rest wouldn't run.

I need to be able to get the UDF working & be able to pass two values from the DF into it.

Can anyone help me pleeeease?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as sqlfunc
import argparse, sys
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from datetime import datetime
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import *

#create a context that supports hive
def create_session(appname):
    spark_session = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .appName(appname)\
        .master('yarn')\
        .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://x.net:9083")\
        .enableHiveSupport()\
        .getOrCreate()
    return spark_session

### START MAIN ###
if __name__ == '__main__':
    spark_session = create_session('Eckoh')
    df1 = spark_session.table('design.web_copy').withColumn("fulldom", concat(col("domain"), col("url")))
    df_agg = df1.coalesce(1000)\
        .filter( (df1.fulldom.like('%facebook.com%') | df1.fulldom.like('%twitter.com%')))\
        .select('dt', 'dc', 'fulldom', 'nsvsn', 'version', 'serverport', 'userid', 'optimisedsize', 'sessionid', 'customrepgrp')\
        .withColumn("https", when(col("serverport") == "443", "HTTPS").otherwise("HTTP"))

    df2 = spark_session.table('design.radius_copy').withColumnRenamed('userid', 'userid2').withColumnRenamed('sessionid', 'sessionid2')
    df2_agg = df2.coalesce(1000).select('userid2', 'sessionid2', 'custavp1')

    conditions = [df_agg.sessionid == df2_agg.sessionid2, df_agg.userid == df2_agg.userid2]
    df3 = df_agg.join(df2_agg, conditions, how='left')

    def shield(x):

        return x

    spark_session.udf.register("saveshield", shield)
    spark_udf = sqlfunc.udf(shield, StringType())
    df4 = df3.withColumn('get_profile', spark_udf(df3['custavp1']))
    df4.show()
    df4.createOrReplaceTempView("tt")
    finaldf = spark_session.sql("create Table keenek1.dftest111 as select * from tt")
```

Comment: `pyspark` is not installed on your python path of workers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the script runs without the UDF so surely it must be installed on all nodes, otherwise that would fail too?

Comment: I have the same problem. pyspark code is running fine until I try to define and execute a udf. useful answers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - at least on the cluster I was using, there was a difference between specifying `.master('yarn')` inside the Python script and using the command-line argument `--master=yarn` to `spark-submit`. The first way caused exactly the error you describe; with the latter my Python script with UDF worked.

It is a bizarre behavior and I have no idea why there is a difference, but it did fix the issue for me.